# Find to closest higher and lower number in an array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, compare

Heyo,

I´m actually try to implement a function that takes an integer as input.
I´ve also have an array of ascendent integer numbers.

Now i´ve try to find the closest lower and closest higher number to my single integer.

I´ve like to return it as an array but I´ve only found a solution to find THE one closest number to a given input.

```java
public int getClosestTimeValue(int time) {
int nearest = -1;
int bestDistanceFoundYet = Integer.getInteger(null);
int[] array = null;     
// We iterate on the array...
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     // if we found the desired number, we return it.
if (array[i] == time) {
    return array[i];
    } else {
        int d = Math.abs(time - array[i]);
if (d < bestDistanceFoundYet) {
    nearest = array[i];
}
    }
}
    return nearest;
}
```

Has anyone an idea how I can solve this problem in java?

Thank you, Lucas

Comment: This code it's not yours, right?

Comment: do you mean sorted when you say 'ascendent'? If so, you could use binary search to find the number in the array.

Comment: your bestDistanceFoundYet is always null.. You have to use it ..

Comment: Side note: The apostrophe is this character: `'` Not this one: `\``

Comment: You could use the Java Map probably TreeMap. Use the floor and ceiling methods of TreeMap (also lower and higher) . You can do this in a few lines on code

Comment: @rpax No found this code here on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not required to use an array directly, then you can use a [NavigableSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/NavigableSet.html) and the ceiling()/floor() methods to get the nearest greater/lesser elements in the set. Example:

```
NavigableSet<Integer> values = new TreeSet<Integer>();
for (int x : array) { values.add(x); }
int lower = values.floor(time);
int higher = values.ceiling(time);
```

If you are required to use an array (homework?) then find a good reference on binary search.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you are searching for one time only. To find both the closest lower and closest higher time, you should have two variables. Then you can check whether the iterated time is lower or higher than the input and store the values in corresponding variables. Also at the moment you are returning only one value, but in order to return multiple values, you should do it through an array.

I'm not sure whether it answers your question, but here's how I would solve the problem:

```
array = new int[]; // Array of times you have declared elsewhere.

// Method which returns the array of found times.
public int[] getClosestTime(int time) {
    int closestLowerTime = 0;
    int closestHigherTime = 100; // Value bigger than the largest value in the array.
    times = new int[2]; // Array for keeping the two closest values.
    // Iterating the array.
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Finding the two closest values.
        int difference = time - array[i];
        if (difference > 0 && array[i] > closestLowerTime) {
            closestLowerTime = array[i];
        } else if (difference < 0 && array[i] < closestHigherTime) {
            closestHigherTime = array[i];
        }
    }
    times[0] = closestLowerTime;
    times[1] = closestHigherTime;
    return times;
}
```

This finds both the closest lower and higher value and returns them as an array. At the moment I solved it as the times were between 0 and 100, but in case you don't know the largest time value, you can find it through another loop which iterates through the array and stores the largest value in `closestHigherTime`. I didn't find a proper way to return the exact value through an array, but is it required?

Answer (score 0):

As the array is sorted....

```
1) Check the middle two elements ..if both are less than the number check the left half (.i.e repeat step1)
else if both are greater than the number repeat step1 for right half...else the selected two numbers are your required answer
```